# Time Complexity of Russian Peasant Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, runtime, multiplication

I'm trying to figure out the time complexity of this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
unsigned int russianPeasant(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    int result = 0; 
    while (b > 0)
    {
        if (b & 1)
            result = result + a;    
        a = a << 1;
        b = b >> 1;
    }
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    unsigned int a,b;
    cout << "Enter two numbers to multiply" << endl;
    cin >> a >> b;
    cout << "product: "<< russianPeasant(a, b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

(from [here](https://iq.opengenus.org/russian-peasant-multiplication-algorithm/))

I'm seeing on some websites it's O(logn), but I know the fastest time complexity for integer multiplication is O(nlogn). What is the time complexity and how does it compare to other multiplication algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two important points to consider when comparing claims about time complexity:

1. There is [bit complexity and arithmetic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity#Others). The choice has an impact on how we assess the complexity of the addition and bit shift operations that occur in the code. When assessing code that uses fixed sized integers, like `unsigned int`, then arithmetic complexity is the right choice. But if we take a more theoretical approach where numbers have no limited range, then bit complexity is the choice to make.
2. We need to agree on what  means. When you recall that *"...the fastest time complexity for integer multiplication is O(nlogn)"* then be aware that here  refers to the *number of digits* of the operands. While those that state a time complexity of O(log) for the code you presented, define  as the *value* of the input, i.e. + (or max(, )).

If we would define  as the number of digits in  and , then the complexity becomes O(). If we would not define the input with the `unsigned int` data type, but some `BigInteger` data type (which allows for an arbitrary number of digits in the input numbers), the addition and shift operations no longer have a constant time (bit) complexity, but O().

So now we are on the same terms and can really compare:

With  defined as the number of digits in the input numbers, and support for arbitrary large numbers, the presented code has a O(²) time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Here n is the size in bits of the parameters.

If it is an algorithm (means that int type is not bounded in size). You pass O(n) times in the while loop, but inside the loop there is an addition which takes O(n) times. Thus O(n^2) at the end. This provided that shifting is in constant time (but a clever data structure can lead to it).

But as we know the size of ints, all of this can be considered as constant time.